# What does this ridiculous glog mean?

Tags: mercurial

Can anyone help me understand this crazy glog? It looks to me like somebody sat on local changes for weeks, but why does the graph collapse like that when there's no merge?

```
o    changeset:   9584:ee55eaad973f
|\   user:        abcd
| |  date:        Tue Jul 03 15:16:36 2012 +0100
| |  summary:     blablabla
| |
| \
| |\
| | \
| | |\
| | | \
| | | |\
| | | | \
| | | | |\
| | | | | \
| | | | | |\
| | | | | | \
| | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | \
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |\
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+---o  changeset:   9581:1425f32ed0fd
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |/   parent:      9467:3a818f1ddee5
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    user:        abcd
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    date:        Tue Jul 03 14:49:22 2012 +0100
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    summary:     blablablabla
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+---o  changeset:   9466:06e3a96051d2
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |/   parent:      9404:59af59ad22e2
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    user:        abcd
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    date:        Wed Jun 27 16:29:56 2012 +0100
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    summary:     blablabla
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+---o  changeset:   9012:c7eecec9dfb5
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    branch:      some branch
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    parent:      8988:292fcb6476ff
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    user:        efgh
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    date:        Mon May 28 16:40:50 2012 +0100
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    summary:     blablabla
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+---o  changeset:   8941:98fae217d622
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |/   parent:      8873:987a6e5ee24f
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    user:        ijklm
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    date:        Wed May 23 10:16:54 2012 +0100
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |    summary:     blablablabla
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Comment: Never seen anything like that, but I like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

> but why does the graph collapse like that when there's no merge?

Why "there's no merge"?  A lot of branches without activity except two-three most recent and this freshest (most right) branch was merged to oldest (default?)

Comment: Well, not between all of those heads. And when you say "a lot of branches", they're not named branches, do you mean heads? I had thought that the heads had to be expicitly merged together, so n heads would need n-1 merges..?

Comment: @jambox - 1. anonymous branches **are branches** in mercurial 2. Some commits belons to named branches (9012, at least) "n heads would need n-1 merges..?" - yes